# Conjecture about the prime number function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-mathematics, conjectures

Define $p_{n,m}$ by 
$p_{n,1}=p_n$ and 
$p_{n,m}=p_{p_{n,m-1}}$,
where $p_n$ is the prime number function.

Conjecture:
$n^n<p_{n,n}< (n+1)^{(n+1)}$

I've only tested it for $n=1,\dots,11.$

I need help testing the conjecture for $n>11$ and to prove it.  Perhaps the conjecture is a consequence of PNT?

```
 n         n^n     p_{n,n}  (n+1)^{n+1}
 1            1             2             4
 2            4             5            27
 3           27            31           256
 4          256           277          3125
 5         3125          5381         46656
 6        46656         87803        823543
 7       823543       2269733      16777216
 8     16777216      50728129     387420489
 9    387420489    1559861749   10000000000
10  10000000000   64988430769  285311670611
11 285311670611 2428095424619 8916100448256
```

Calculate $p_{n,m}$ by m times iteration:
1. $p_{n,1}=p_n$
2. $p_{n,2}=p_{p_{n,1}}$
..
m. $p_{n,m}=p_{p_{n,m-1}}$

Comment: No, it is false for $n=9$. You can test it at https://primes.utm.edu/nthprime/index.php

Comment: The superscript portion of the $p_n^m$ notation strikes me as somewhat confusing, since it's mixed in with exponential superscript notation.  I would suggest $p_{m,n}=p_{p_{m-1,n}}$.

Comment: I will change..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a lower bound $p_n>n\log n$, one can show that $\log{p_{n,m}}>\log{p_{n,m-1}}+\log\log{p_{n,m-1}}$. By computer, one can check that $\log{p_{26,26}}>89.0>\log27^{27}$.

It looks like always $\log{p_{n,n}}>\log(n+1)^{n+1}$ for $n\ge26$, but I can't prove it...

Comment: You may be right. The upper bound seems non-valid. A user compared with Sterlings formula and that looks like a good idea: to multiply $n^n$ with a growing function $>1$.